# Aspx page redirecting to generic page instead of requested url

Tags: html, asp.net, url

I'm having some trouble getting to a certain page. When we click on this link the Subway website overrides it and send it to their generic page and you have to actually look up the specific store instead of being taken directly to it.

https://order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx#12009

The 12009 that's passed as a parameter actually corresponds to a store. If I manually look up that store, I get that same URL, however I am unable to use that specific URL to get to that store. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You could try digging through the JavaScript that comes down when you load the page to see if there's something in there that might look at query string as opposed to the fragment. But in general, looks like a bad design to me as the URL should correspond to the state of the webpage.

Comment: I'm really confused. Is this a question about how to use the Subway website? Or are you trying to automate something? What? Also, just so you know, 12009 isn't really passed as a *parameter*, per se, it's a hash. Sure, it's a type of parameter, but that's something of a buzz-word here since it implies "query parameter," which that most certainly is not.

Comment: +Matthew Haugen I've generated a QR code to that URL which should ideally take the customer to that store's page, but it is taking them to the generic page instead.

Comment: You'll have to change the QR code to point to a different URL. The question is, is there a URL that exists for that store on Subways site? Are you sure you want to link to the subway site, instead of perhaps some other site with info about that particular location?

Comment: @mason If you go to the page I linked, and type in any zip code then click on one of the stores, that's the page I'm trying to get the user to. The URL of that page is of the same format I linked.

Comment: @SKLAK I *know* what you're trying to do. But I'm saying it's not possible for you change how URL's work on their site. You could suggest to Subway that they change their site, but you can't control their site. That's why I was suggesting alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The #12009 is a bookmark on the page, rather than a link to a distinct page for the store. In this case, my *guess* is the bookmark is used as a technique to remember the information between post-backs. This way, the site knows which store you previously selected when you then click the "Order" or "Directions" links. The Subway.com web page apparently doesn't examine this when the page is initially loaded, so it just displays the generic info.

What you're trying to do sounds like a great idea. If you're really ambitious you could look at the page source to see if a hack is possible. Maybe pass this idea on to Subway?

Comment: Hmm, I noticed a javascript function is being called to which the hash is being passed. Is there a way to call a javascript function via the URL?

Comment: @SKLAK No, there is not.